# a will that harvest

Tags: meaning-in-context

"We pulled with a will that harvest, Topthorn and I, hauling in the heavy hay wagons to the barns where Emilie and her grandfather would unload. "

i am confused on the first half. Does "a will that harvest" mean "a strong will"? If yes then what does "harvest" function in this phrase?

Comment: Find the meaning of the phrase "with a will".  Put it (as an adverb) in the middle of "We pulled that harvest."

Comment: What @GEdgar said. But note that the cited example is a literary inversion ("anastrophe")  that wouldn't *normally* be used. The "standard English" sequence would have the adverbial component at the end, not between the verb and its object: *We **pulled that harvest with a will**, Topthorn and I,...*

Comment: I don't think it is a literary inversion, because I don't think _that harvest_ is the object of the verb: I think it is another adverbial phrase. I think _pull_ is intransitive here.

Comment: Yes. Parallel to _We ate with a will that Thanksgiving_. Note that this confusion is only possible in writing; in speech it wouldn't be confusing.

Comment: **We pulled energetically during that harvest time.**

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I read it as being analogous to "We worked hard that summer" or "We stayed indoors that winter". In my opinion the writer is using 'harvest' as a designation of a period of time as well as a description of an activity.